# I would like to delete an object within my bucket/project but when I try it fails. I also don't have the option to move or rename objects

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have made some mistakes that I would like to rectify within Google Cloud Storage but I can't seem to change anything once it's created in Google Cloud Storage.

I click on the object I want to delete, press delete, but every time it fails. IT doesn't give me any information as to why.

I have tried looking on the support pages but the advice they give doesn't work - at the three dots menu for each object I don't have the option to rename or move objects, and the process for deleting always fails.

I am not confident at using command line instructions so won't be trying that (I'm not the only person in my organisation using the storage platform and don't want to accidentally delete anything that's not mine. There is no one within my organisation who can help).

I have tried editing the permissions but this seems to have no effect.

I'm not able to upgrade to an account that allows more support, as this is an organisational account for work.

I would really appreciate help with this. It seems like it should be a simple fix but the interface doesn't seem to be user-friendly to those who aren't programmers. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons why you might be unable to delete objects. You may not be have the right permissions:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-permissions#object_permissions

note that depending on how your bucket is configured you may need specific permissions on the object in question:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control

Note also that your administrator may have set retention policies at the Bucket and/or object level, which could prevent you from deleting the object:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/bucket-lock